# Java Inheritance Issue

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class car1 {}
class car2 {}
class car3 {}
class car4 {}
```

Support I also have the method: queryCar()

```
private Object queryCar()
{
     int version = getCarVersion(); // returns car version
     if (version == 1)
         return new car1();
     else if (version == 2)
         return new car2();
     else if (version == 3)
         return new car3();
     ...
}
```

I have another method, doStuff()

```
private void doStuff()
{
     // psudocode
     if queryCar() returns a car1, I want to create a JPanel with an instance member of type car1
}
```

How do I accomplish said psudocode? InstanceOf works for determining the class.  However, I only want one class to autogenerate that car on runttime. (Thinking of an analog of C++ pointers in java)

Comment: I didn't understand the problem with `instanceof`

Comment: Yeah, did you actually try this before posting?

Comment: I want to be able to downcast the "car" variable to any type of car (car1, car2, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `instanceof` with `Object` like you did, but it might make it easier to use a car interface like this:

```
interface Car {}
class Car1 implements Car {}

private void doStuff {
    Car car = queryCar();
    if(car instanceof Car1) {
        Car1 theCar = ((Car1) car);
        theCar.car1OnlyMethod();
        //Or
        ((Car1) car).car1OnlyMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `if (car instanceof Car1)`? I'm guessing that's why someone downvoted.

Comment: Yes, I typed it out too quickly and missed the `1`.  I fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Can I access Car1's instance members in your doStuff method? Is it possible to downcast the variable, car, to a car1?

Answer (score 5):

You should use inheritance do do what you need.

```
abstract class Car {
    public Car queryCar();
    public int getCarVersion();
    public void doStuff() {
        JPanel j = new JPanel();
        j.add(new JLabel(queryCar().getCarVersion()));
    }
}

class Car1 extends Car {
    public Car queryCar() { return new Car1(); }
    public int getCarVersion() { return 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much common behaviour you have between your `carN` classes. In Java, everything automatically extends Object so you always have a common base class, but Object is probably not a particularly *useful* common base.

Generally, put common behaviour in, say, `Car` and add or override version-specific behaviour in each of the subclasses.

EDIT: In your `doStuff` method you should consider carefully whether you *really* need to inspect the subclass. It will be difficult to maintain if you do require different behaviour for each subclass, so you should think about whether you can move some logic into the `carN` classes or the `Car` superclass and remove the dependency. If you can write your `doStuff` in terms of a more general `Car` interface/superclass then your code will be cleaner and easier to understand and maintain.